# Dumb Question: What's the difference between PlayerView and SimpleExoPlayerView?

Tags: java, android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I'm writing a library around ExoPlayer (creating a simple View that can be dragged and dropped into an app and will play videos and advertisements per our company's business logic). As I'm looking to tweak the display of this player, I Googled the obvious ("how to change appearance of exoplayer") and I keep seeing references to `SimpleExoPlayerView`. But from my understanding I should be placing a `PlayerView` onto my layout, not a `SimpleExoPlayerView`

What is the difference between these two classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now, after reading the [documentation](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/SimpleExoPlayerView.html), I noted that the only difference I could see is that `SimpleExoPlayerView` is deprecated:

> Deprecated. Use PlayerView.

Therefore, and although it could have made a difference in the past, use `PlayerView`.

Answer (score 2):

`PlayerView` is deprecated too, use `StyledPlayerView` instead. Google, please stop it.

Answer (score 0):

`'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.18.1'` with version you should use `StyledPlayerView` because `PlayerView` deprecated.

[image]